# What does error 1452 "a foreign key constraint fails" during an insert mean?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

So I am trying to add information to a table in phpMyAdmin, but it will not let me 'add or update a child row' with error code #1452.

```
INSERT INTO tblBooking (BookingRef, AppRef, BookingDate, TableNo, Verified, VerifyStaffID, bPassword)

VALUES ('1', '1', '2021-03-05', 'Table 1', 'Y', '2', 'Password123'),
('2', '1', '21-01-07', 'Table 2', 'N', '3', 'Chain'),
('3', '2', '20-11-02', 'Table 3', 'Y', '1', 'aSecret'),
('4', '3', '20-12-06', 'Table 2', 'Y', '4', 'Pedal')
```

I get this error:[error description][image: 1]

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The error message is pretty clear here, check your foreign keys. It seems it's working as intended (blocking the insert to protect DB integrity)  _or_ your FK is setup incorrectly.

Comment: On a side note: `'21-01-07'` is ambiguous. What is the year, the month, the day? Use proper date literals instead of mere strings: `DATE '2021-01-07'` for January 7, 2021.

Answer (score 1):

MYSQL is complaining about a FK that doesn't exists in the parent table , so in your case one or more than one of the VerifyStaffID values  ( 1, 3 , 4)  doesn't exists in the parent table (tblstaff)